# Javascript closures gotcha

Tags: javascript, settimeout

For some reason, my code isn't behaving as it is supposed to. I'm convinced that there's nothing wrong with the code but it seems as though I'm unable to see it. Please help me understand what's going on. The code is supposed to loop through and display the numbers 10-0 after 2 second interval.ie. 10-9-8..each after 2 seconds. It displays the numbers after 2 second intervals but it displays them in ascending order instead of descending. I'd really like to use a for loop and not a workaround. Below is my code.

```
function fadeOut(elem)
{
    for( var i=10; i>0; i-- )
    {
        (function(index)
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                console.log(index);
            }, index * 2000);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 *2000 > 1*2000. You're iterating the array backwards the the math still makes the timeouts go ascending. Maybe (10-index+1)*2000

Comment: @dman2306 That should be the answer

Comment: @dman2306 dammit, that was it. thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you do is say, "In 10 seconds, print '10'."

Then you say, "In 9 seconds, print '9'."

And so on all the way down.  "In 1 seconds, print '1'."

And 999 milliseconds later, it does the last thing you asked and prints "1".

Try:

```
function fadeOut(elem)
{
    for( var i=10; i>0; i-- )
    {
        (function(index)
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                console.log(index);
            }, (10-index) * 2000);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates 10 timeouts which are:

- In 10 seconds - log 10
- In  9 seconds - log  9
- In  8 seconds - log  8
- In  7 seconds - log  7

...

- In  1 seconds - log  1

What you want to do is increase the time while decreasing the counter, like this:

```js
function fadeOut(elem)
{
  for ( var i = 10; i > 0; --i )
  {
    (function(index)
     {
      setTimeout( function(){
        console.log(index);
      }, (11-index)*2000);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fadeOut(this)">Click</button>
```